# Minitube via tsocks and tor does not play or download any video

Tags: tor, minitube

I can not open Youtube. Because of government restriction. So when I open minitube, I can not search or watch any video. I used tor and tsocks to open minitube, then I can search by minitube; But whenever I click on any video, It does not show it! How can I find and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minitube has a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/minitube/+bug/990891) which leads to no video output. A workaround is to *install* `phonon-backend-vlc` and to *remove* `phonon-backend-gstreamer`. Several user have reported to get the video output working.

However the deeper reason is a [bug in gstreamer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad0.10/+bug/973014). It seems this was resolved. So the bug fix should slowly moving into Ubuntu.

Comment: Now, tor has been block too here!

Comment: You can switch to Tor Bridges or try to use obfs proxy with Tor.

Comment: Right; `sudo apt-get install tor obfsproxy proxychains` => set tor for using obfs by editing `/etc/tor/torrc` (search for more info), you can find obfs2 proxies here: https://bridges.torproject.org/?transport=obfs3 and obfs3 here: https://bridges.torproject.org/?transport=obfs3 => then, Alt+F2 => 1.`torify minitube` or 2. `proxychains minitube`; You can also use firefox instead of minitube: **firefox** + **foxyproxy** + **tor**; If you use minitube as a downloading tool, you can replace it with [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl)